# Is there an analogue of the Fourier transform based on hyperbolic trig functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Is there something analogous to Fourier series or the Fourier transform but which is based on hyperbolic trig functions rather than $\sin, \cos$, and $\exp$?

Comment: In some sense the analogue is the Laplace transform, that is the analytic continuation of the Fourier transform

Comment: Is there a sense in which $\cosh(kx), \sinh(kx), k \ge 1$ are orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

$\ln|1+x|=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$

Let $e^y=1+x$.

Then $y=(e^y-1)-(e^y-1)^2/2+...$

and we know $e^{ky}=\cosh ky + \sinh ky$.

$(e^y-1)^n = \sum _{k=0}^n C(n,k)(\cosh ky + \sinh ky)(-1)^{n-k}$

$y= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^nC(n,k)(\cosh ky +\sinh ky)(-1)^{k+1}/n $